Performance of the tokio-postgres driver in rust on simple example
I'm interested in the performance of the tokio-postgres driver in rust
use tokio_postgres::{NoTls};
use tokio::time::Instant;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let (client, connection) = tokio_postgres::connect("...", NoTls).await?;

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(e) = connection.await {
            eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
        }
    });

    let start = Instant::now();

    let rows = client.query("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT col1 FROM public.test_table WHERE col1 = '15000000'", &[]).await?;
    println!("> Query time: {:?}", start.elapsed());

    let start_time_1 = Instant::now();
    for row in rows {
        let value: &str = row.get(0);
        println!("{}", value);
    }
    println!("> Loop time: {:?} / Full time: {:?}", start_time_1.elapsed(), start.elapsed());

    Ok(())
}

Result:
> Query time: 2.2302ms
Index Only Scan using idx_test_table_col1 on test_table  (cost=0.43..4.45 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.093..0.094 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (col1= '15000000'::text)
  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.658 ms
Execution Time: 0.134 ms
> Loop time: 2.3609ms / Full time: 4.8276ms

How did 0.134ms turn into 2.2302ms and why did the iteration take 2.3609ms? Is it possible to speed up these processes? If this is normal, then please say so.
Note:

I know this is an example from the documentation, I took it as the basis for the question.
I also tested sqlx and got the same results.
When using a parameterized query "Select ... FROM ... WHERE col1 = $1" ($1 = random value) the result is the same, that is, using &[] has no effect
jdbc test shows that 10 users can make 15705 rps (during 120s), and this code - 2850 rps. ConnectionPool is equal. Java better?


"How did 0.134ms turn into 2.2302ms?" -- Network latency, unmarshalling, etc. This should not be a problem with in a multi-threaded environment unless you are serializing many calls. What's the issue? The engine is only spending 0.134 ms in the execution; that's the important part. The planning time will go away after a few executions. The network latencies are not going to be important in multi-users environments.

In DBeaver/Jmeter (or another jdbc) query execution time is equal time of explain analyze - There is not Network latency, unmarshalling, etc?. It doesn’t matter if I execute the request once, or arrange a stress test (jmeter), the request time always turns from 0.0x to 2.1x ms. I connected to localhost. The problem is the lack of understanding why this happens and whether it should happen at all, that the query execution time increases by 10-20 times

One way or another, the jdbc test shows that 10 users can make 15705 rps (during 120s), and this code - 2850 rps. ConnectionPool is equal

Your "Query time: 2.2302ms" isn't measured by the DB but by your Rust code, so it will definitely include network and at least some marshaling.

You're also timing a bunch of println, which is notoriously slow (in any language, but you didn't show the java code so we can't know if it prints too). Plus, very short timings like that are always very imprecise and inflated (your jdbc test averages over two minutes)


jdbc test shows that 10 users can make 15705 rps (during 120s), and this code - 2850 rps. ConnectionPool is equal. Java better?

It wouldn't be a blanket statement like "Java is better faster", but many factors including the optimization of their Postgres database driver and client library. But without seeing the Java code and knowing it's running on the same hardware, we can't say.


How did 0.134ms turn into 2.2302ms

Correction, its 0.792 ms into 2.2302 ms. The server took 0.658 ms to create a plan for the query and then 0.134 ms executing it.
Planning Time: 0.658 ms
Execution Time: 0.134 ms

Let's look at what you're actually measuring.
   let start = Instant::now();

    let rows = client.query("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT col1 FROM public.test_table WHERE col1 = '15000000'", &[]).await?;
    println!("> Query time: {:?}", start.elapsed());

Here you are measuring the time to...

Run client.query.
Send the query to the server.
Wait for the server to receive the query.
The server converts the text of the query into an execution plan. (0.658 ms)
The server executes the query and gets the results. (0.134 ms)
The server sends the result back.
Wait for the client to receive the results.
Convert the result into a Result<Vec<row>>.

The part in bold is what is happening on the server. The rest is either waiting around or things your code is doing, that accounts for the other 1.44 ms. Yes, there is network latency on even a local server.

why did the iteration take 2.3609ms

Because computers take time to do things.
    let start_time_1 = Instant::now();
    for row in rows {
        let value: &str = row.get(0);
        println!("{}", value);
    }
    println!("> Loop time: {:?} / Full time: {:?}", start_time_1.elapsed(), start.elapsed());


Allocate row.
Enter the loop.
Call Row::get.
Print it.
Wait for the print to complete. (Printing takes time. It's I/O just like writing to a file.)
Exit the loop.

Why did that take 2.3609ms? I can't say. You could profiling your code to find the bottleneck.

Yes you are right. Total time = planning time and execution time. By running queries using jdbc I meant using jmeter, although I have code in java, it showed better results than rust. My main problem was that I did not realize that the delays in other stages could be so large, more than the execution of basic requests

@Dvashington Timing a single instance of a very fast operation risks being overwhelmed by the supporting code and things like memory allocation and i/o. This is why benchmarks normally do many, many iterations. I'll be curious if profiling reveals any hot spots.
